# How to disable Application code scan in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

[ADO Pipline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gl9Q.png)
[ADO steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdOUv.png)

How to disable the automatic scan that runs in ADO Azure pipeline ?

Comment: Euhm, edit the job and disable the step?

Comment: thanks for response in the steps i have attached there is no steps mentioned. In tasks git repo i searched in options there is no step related to code scan

Comment: @kumaresh  is scan step mentioned in maven pom.xml file? and also check your pipeline yaml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

code scan was enabled on overall project solved after moving the project to unscanned folder

Comment: neither your question nor the unswear is helpful, I am voting to close the question.